# CreateDataPartition Not Working

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, lme4

I am trying to partition data into train and test sets for cross validation. I use the following line to split the data on a factor variable representing the state, which has many levels. I use the line based on other posts which indicate that `createDataPartition` from the `caret`package should split within factors.

```
inTrain = createDataPartition(y = LM_full$state, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = F)
LM_full_train=LM_full[inTrain,]
LM_full_test=LM_full[-inTrain,]
```

I then try to fit a linear model on the training data and to predict the values for the test data, but it always says that I nave new levels in the test data. I compared the levels of state for the training and the test datasets and they're the same, so it seems like there should be a level of the variable present in both the train and test data.

```
> unique(LM_full_train$state) == unique(LM_full_test$state)
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[19] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Here is the error:

```
> lm2_pred <- predict(lm2, LM_full_test, type = "response")
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor state has new levels CT, MA, NH, NJ, RI
```

How do I avoid this error / split the training and test data such that there is a level for each factor present in the training and test data?

Comment: This isn't quite reproducible.  Could you provide a representative dataset (if you can't provide the entire thing), set some seeds (`set.seed`) and show how you created your model?

Comment: The solution that always works so that you don't have to worry about this is one: DUMMIFY the factor variable yourself! P.S. if you need more help you need to give us a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add the new levels to the model.

```
lm2$xlevels[["state"]] = union(lm2$xlevels[["state"]] , levels(LM_full_test$state))
```

Comment: This needs more recognition!